Having an overloaded function once generically and an optional automatic conversion
What are the reasons according to the standard for the following code that the string's constructor with a char-pointer isn't called ?
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fn( string const &str )
{
    cout << str;
}

template<typename T>
void fn( T param )
{
    cout << param << endl;
}

int main()
{
    fn( string( "hello world" ) );
    fn( "hello world" );
}


The template T will be a perfect match for anything. The string requires a conversion, which has lower points.

@BoP That's what I also guess, but what does the standard say ?

The standard says a lot! There is an entire chapter called Overloading, containing 30 pages of odd rules. The very short version is that templates will lose if equally good match, but wins if other functions require conversions and the template does not.

See dupe: C++ Function overloading using const parameters

Read "Overload resolution" chapter: especially [over.match] and [over.match.best]. There is "function F1 is defined to be a better (...) if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than (...)", so in your case fn(T) doesn't need the conversion to std::string, while the other function needs.

@EdisonvonMyosotis I've reopened your question. Are you asking only about the second call fn( "hello world" ); or both the first and the second call. If you only asking about second call then you can remove the first call. That will make your question more concise.


What are the reasons according to the standard for the following code that the string's constructor with a char-pointer isn't called ?

For the second call fn("hello world");, the function template's parameter param doesn't need a conversion to std::string while the non-function template requires a conversion to std::string.
That is, the function template is a better match than the non-function template for the call fn("hello world");
